# How to add Results for loop to List

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, revit-api

I working with a revit code to collect CurveLoops and create a loft geometry.

Creating the CurveLoops is working fine with a for loop(creates lines from points). But it creates two separate CurveLoops.

I've tried to add the for loop result to a new list(profile3). But it returns two list with one CurveLoop in it. In my case it should be two CurveLoops in one list(profile3)

```cs
CurveLoop profileLoop = new CurveLoop();

List<CurveLoop> profile3 = new List<CurveLoop>();

SolidOptions options = new SolidOptions(ElementId.InvalidElementId,
ElementId.InvalidElementId);

for (int i = 0; i < p.Count - 1; ++i)
{
    // Create lines and convert points to mm
    Line line = Line.CreateBound(p[i] / 304.8, p[i + 1] / 304.8);
    //Append points to CurveLoop
    profileLoop.Append(line);
}

//Here I want to add both created CurveLoops to list
profile3.Add(profileLoop);

//Create Loft
Solid loft = GeometryCreationUtilities.CreateLoftGeometry(profile3
    , options);
```

Loft can't be created because it only has one curveloop in the list and it needs both created from the for loop

*First CurveLoop and Second CurveLoop that should be in one list*
[image: First CurveLoop and Second CurveLoop that should be connected]

Comment: I can't really see where you are creating 2 CurveLoops.. I only see 1 Curveloop object

Comment: Did you post all of your code? There is only one `Curveloop` object here.

Comment: From the [API](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2016/84824924-cb89-9e20-de6e-3461f429dfd6.htm), CurveLoop seems to be a collectinon of Curves... Maybe that's where the confusion arised?

Comment: it creates two CurveLoops from two list with both 9 points in it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add the same `CurveLoop` to the list twice. So you will end up with one list with two matching elements.

I would suggest doing a second `profile3.Add(profileLoop);`

You aren't really creating two different `CurveLoops` in that for iterator, just one. So you would need to add it twice to the list in order for your result to work.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

What you are doing here is passing the same object multiple times into a list and then wonder how come all the objects in the list are the same.

### Solution

You might want to look at the concept of [passing by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_reference_parameters.htm) and the difference between [reference types and value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/object).